# Virgin modem not providing IP address to Linux server

Tags: linux, networking, router, dhcp, broadband

I have a Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) server connected to a Virgin Media Home Hub 3 in modem mode. I am trying to get an IP address via DHCP. It consistently times out.

Connecting a DD-WRT router to the home hub gets an IP address every time, so the connection and modem both work.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is your server the only computer connected to your modem? You will need an actual router if it is not.

Comment: Yes it is the only computer connected to the modem.

Comment: If that's the case you might want to check the settings of your modem. Especially, try to find the "DHCP" settings and make sure that it is enabled. Maybe "modem mode" disables it? This is device-specific, so I can't really help with that...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, rebooting the Virgin modem allowed a connection to be made...

I wouldn't really say "fixed" but at least I have a connection now.

Comment: The Virgin modems (at least they used to when I had a Virgin connection) remember the MAC of the last device attached and only give an IP to that MAC. Rebooting resolves this.

Comment: That would explain it! :)